# UIViewController Animation ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

Trying to create something like below in Objective-C, this is available in Swift.
I tried using bridging etc, to use this code with my Objective C project but it's having import issues.

In Objective-C I tried below things and partially it works for UIView, but I guess I need to add transitions to complete UIViewController.

[image]

What I tried

```
- (IBAction)menuButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(menuButtonPressed)]) {
        [self.delegate menuButtonPressed];
    }
    if (!isVertical) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.6
                              delay: 0.0
             usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3
              initialSpringVelocity: .8
                            options: 0
                         animations: ^
         {
             self.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, -240, 0);
             self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, 90 * M_PI / 180);
             self.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, 240, 0);
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             isVertical = YES;

                         }
         ];

    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.45
                              delay: 0.0
             usingSpringWithDamping: 0.44
              initialSpringVelocity: .8
                            options: 0
                         animations: ^
         {
             self.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, -240, 0);
             self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, -90 * M_PI / 180);
             self.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, 240, 0);

         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             isVertical = NO;

                         }
         ];
    }
}
```

Any inputs will be helpful.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what , exactly you are facing the problem, It is possible while elaborating more, you yourself give the answer !!!

Comment: I am trying to achieve custom transition of UIViewController which would look like in gif.

Comment: It's on GitHub - just google iOS guillotine menu
https://github.com/Yalantis/GuillotineMenu

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple implementation that you can use to animate transitions between view controllers. You could basically use the same animation gist if you want to use it with UIViews.

```
let generateRandomColor: Void -> UIColor = {
    let red = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
    let green = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
    let blue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
    return UIColor(red:red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
}

class SlideAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    let presenting: Bool

    init(presenting: Bool) {
        self.presenting = presenting
        super.init()
    }

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()!

        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

        var animatingView: UIView
        var initialTransform: CGAffineTransform
        var finalTransform: CGAffineTransform

        if presenting {
            containerView.addSubview(toView)
            animatingView = toView
            initialTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
            finalTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        } else {
            containerView.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)
            animatingView = fromView
            initialTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            finalTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
        }

        animatingView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        animatingView.frame = containerView.bounds
        animatingView.transform = initialTransform

        UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext), delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 16, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
            animatingView.transform = finalTransform
            }) {
            _ in
                toView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
                toView.frame = containerView.bounds
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }
    }

}

class PresentedViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = generateRandomColor()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
            action: "tapped")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func tapped() {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}

class TestViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = generateRandomColor()
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
            action: "tapped")
        definesPresentationContext = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func tapped() {
        let presentedViewController = PresentedViewController()
        presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
        presentedViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        presentViewController(presentedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return SlideAnimationController(presenting: true)
    }

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return SlideAnimationController(presenting: false)
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, would have been more helpful if in Objective-C.

Comment: Check this sample project to get more details on how to transition in objective c https://github.com/ariok/TB_CustomTransition